# OOP programming in python

Tags: python, oop

I was reading Dietel's C++ programming book. In this book they mention how a programmer should release only the interface part of his code and not the implementation.

So carrying this over to python:

I have 2 files: 
1) the implementation file = accountClass.py and 
2) the interface file = useAccountClass.py

I have compiled the implementation file and have obtained the .pyc file. So when I provide my code to someone else, I would provide him with the .pyc file and the interface file, right?

Also, if I provide someone else with ONLY the .pyc file, can I expect him to write the interface on his own? I'm going to say no. But there's this one nagging doubt that I have:

The creators of numpy and scipy did not share the implementation with us end users. And I don't think they shared any interfaces either. But we can still search for the different classes and their methods inside both numpy and scipy. So, using this example of numpy and scipy, I guess what I'm trying to ask is:

Is it possible for someone else to create an interface to my code if I provide him/ her with only the compiled implementation file (in this case accountClass.pyc)? How will that person know what classes and methods I have defined in my implementation? I mean, will they use the

```
if __name__ = "__main__" : 
    blah blah
```

or is there some other way??

Comment: Actually numpy and scipy are open-source, so the implementation is readily available.  `.pyc` files can be decompiled, so you aren't actually hiding much by distributing only those files.  It is generally difficult to obscure code in scripting languages.

Comment: Upvoted the question because it expose a very deep misconception/misunderstanding of what encapsulation is all about and how stupid text books can lead otherwise probably sane persons to do stupid things.

Answer (score 4):

You got that *entirely* wrong. Or perhaps it's a horrible book whose author got something seriously wrong. Code using other code should indeed, barring significant counterarguments, adhere to an interface and not care about the details of the implementation. However, even in the world of static compilation to machine code (e.g. C++), this does not mean you should lock away the source code of the implementation.

Whether someone has access to the implementation, and whether they make use of that knowledge while writing a specific piece of code, are completely different issues. Heck, even the author of the implementation can/should still program to an interface when working on other code (e.g. other modules). Likewise, even if you lock the implementation away from someone, they may very well rely on implementation quirks which are not part of the interface. If anyone in the world of static compilation to machine code provides only headers and object files, and not the source code, it's because the projects are closed source, not to encourage good programming practices among clients.

In Python, your question makes no sense - there are no "interface" and "implementation" files, there's just code which is run and defines functions, classes, and other values. There is no such thing as an interface file you'd provide. You provide an implementation - and (hopefully) documentation which details both interface and possibly implementation details. And once a module is imported, the class objects, function objects, and other objects, contain plenty of information (including, in many cases, the text from which large parts of the documentation was generated). This is also true for extension modules like numpy. And note that their implementation *is* accessible, it's just not included in all distributions because it's of little use. With Python code, you practically have to distribute the source code because anything else is platform-specific.

On a side note, .pyc files are pretty high level, and easily understood when disassembled (which is as easy as importing the module and running the stdlib module `dis` on any function inside). I consider this a minor technicality as it's already the wrong question to ask.

Comment: 1) There is no concept of interface and implementation in python. 

2) I can write OOP code in python that, say, computes the inverse of a matrix. Now if I give this code of mine to a friend, I just hand over to him my source code. But my idea of OOP was: write the implementation and the interface; give the interface and the compiled implementation file to someone else and not worry that your source code will be used/ changed. In light of what you said, I guess the idea is wrong. But I always thought tht OOP helps protect source code

Comment: By source code i mean the code written in my implementation file. 

Also, i just wanted confirmation on the following - basically i wanted to know if i understood you correctly:

Comment: after reading the comments below, I think that if I wanted to share my code then I can probably give the interface to others and provide them with documentation so that they know what classes; methods in those classes; and attributes of those methods, my implementation code contains. That way they can write their own interfaces. So borrowing again from numpy: I have the "interface" (the module). I use the documentation that the numpy developers have written. I use this documentation to look for the classes/ methods/ attributes i want.

Comment: And following this process, I develop my own code/ "interface". Please confirm whether this idea of mine about OOP in python makes logical sense (I think it does .. maybe :D) Also I'm really sorry for posting so many comments to this one post ... but I really want to understand this idea and where the fault lies when i try to understand this idea about encapsulation

Comment: @Ned Batchelder: Kindly take a look at the comments above

Comment: @heltonbiker: Kindly take a look at the comments above

Comment: Kindly take a look at the comments above

Comment: @user755939 Your idea of OOP in general is flawed. OOP is independent of compilation, and does not protect source code. It's a way of structuring programs (short, incomplete definition: by modeling your problem in terms of objects which combine data and behaviour, and letting the objects decide how to do certain things), and like many other paradigms it encourages you *not* to expose *all* details of the implementation. Explicit "interface files" exist in C (which is not an OOP language in any sense of the word) too, via headers. Protecting source code is *entirely* unrelated.

Comment: @user755939 As for confirmation, I'm still not sure what you mean by "interface". Are you thinking of an explicit listing of what a module does? Because there is no such thing, except perhaps informally in documentation. There's a module, this module contains classes, functions, and other data, and that's pretty much it. Some of these things might be prone to change or internal, so they may be marked as implementation detail (or not mentioned at all) in the documentation; their named will often be prefixed with an underscore in Python (just a convention).

Comment: ok, I think I understood the OOP bit. But I still have a question - Microsoft doesn't share the code behind any version of windows does it? But the linux kernel is free to all. So I'm guessing the microsoft programmers release an executable (which is,  in my head, sort of like a compiled bit of code) that doesn't let the user know the code written to generate the executable. So in that sense, they safe guard their implementation right? So that would make windows 7/ windows vista/ windows xp an "interface" to their code right?

Comment: And this definition of interface and implementation is different from the OOP definition right?

Comment: @user755939 I wouldn't speak of interface and implementation in this case. Both Linux and Windows define a multitude of interfaces (win32 API, POSIX APIs, ABIs, system calls, etc.) which hide implementation details - not by preventing access to the implementation, but by allowing other code to *choose* not to know about the implementation. This is indeed different from the OOP definition, in that it's a good idea in ALL programming paradigms. Whether the implementation is disclosed too or not is another issue, mostly a business one. Clients can use or circumvent interfaces either way.

Answer (score 0):

Deitel's advice to C++ programmers doesn't apply to Python, for a number of reasons:

1. Python isn't compiled to machine code, so no matter what form you provide the program in, it will be relatively easy for someone to read the code.
2. Python doesn't have .h and .c files, all you can provide is the .py or .pyc files.
3. Treating code as a secret is kind of silly anyway.  What is in your code that you need to keep hidden from others?

Numpy and Scipy are largely implemented in C, which is why you don't have the source, for your own convenience.  You can get the source if you like.  The "interface" to that code is the module that you can import and then call.

Answer (score 0):

You should not confuse "user interface" with "class interface". If you have a useAccountClass file, that file probably performs some task using the classes and methods defined in the accountClass file, if I understood right.

If you send the file to other person, they are not supposed to "guess" what your compiled class does. That's what DOCUMENTATION is for: a description of the functions contained in the module (compiled or not), which parameters they take, which values they return, and what they are expected to do, the "meaning" of the task they perform.

As an abstract example, let's suppose you have an image processing class. If that class has the function `findCircles(image)`, the documentation should explain that it takes an image, possibly containing circles, and returns a list or array of coordinates of the centers of circles contained in the image. HOW the circles are detected is not important, you don't need to know that to use the function. Now if the function was called like `findCircles(image, gaussian_threshold=10)`, the caller would have to know the function uses some "gaussian_threshold" parameter, that is, the caller would NEED to know about the function's entrails, and in OOP this is Not Good. If you decided to use another algorithm in the future, every code using that function would have to be rewritten, because the `gaussian_threshold` most probably wouldn't make sense anymore.

So, the interface, in OOP, is the abstraction used to communicate to the object only the canonical parameters or inputs it needs to know to perform a task in the language of the problem, not in the language of the implementation (that can change anytime).

The documentation, in this sense, is a contract that assures to the user (in this case, another developer) that the function will perform as expected if sane inputs are given to it.

Now the FINAL USER, a non-technical person wanting to use your program, would need the WHOLE working program (controls and views), not only the class definitions (the model).

Hope this helps, and I must recommend the books "Code Complete 2nd ed." and "Pragmatic Programmer - From Journeyman to Master" as VERY enlightening readings on the broad topic.

Comment: That's a pretty bad example. In numeric computing, you very often want to know what algorithm functions implement, so that you can provide appropriate settings and have some control over their performance (both speed and accuracy).

Comment: @larsmans: that's why experts recommend to choose the level of abstraction of the interface that is most adequate to the problem. In scientific problems, it is actually needed to know the entrails. For most uses (and I agree image processing is not a good example of "most uses"), the computational aspects and the problem-domain aspects of the classes can be, and even should be, uncoupled / transparent to the user/caller/designer, IMO.

Comment: @heltonbiker : so if I need to give my code (written using OOP) to another developer, all I would need to give him would be the documentation and the useAccountClass file right?

Comment: @heltonbiker : also, what's the difference between a user interface and a class interface?

Comment: @user755939 Usually, you separate the business model of your program from the user interface. Each have its classess, and that classes have each their own interface. Actually, "interface" is a broad concept, so in each context it can mean a different thing. But for sure User Interface and Class Interface refer very precisely to two DIFFERENT things: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interface_%28computing%29#Programming_to_the_interface